# What is the use CSS Reset

Tags: css

What is the use of using css reset, if I can edit the styling of any elememt in my css only

example:

```
h1
{
margin:0;
}
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Every browser comes with a default style sheet. 
If you don't overwrite the rules of that default style sheet then this CSS-rules are applied.

Some developers want to get of this styles for starting from scratch on their own. So they start with a so-called browser-reset and then define their own rules.

For more infos and the exact reasons have a look at this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/